# Compiling a Library with Cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, cmake, voxel

I'm trying to include PolyVox, a voxel library, into my project. However the library download does not supply you with precompiled headers and instead requires Cmake. This wouldn't be a huge problem, except that their tutorial on the subject is *extremely* incomplete. I've never used Cmake before, and searching shed no light on the problem.

I've ran Cmake with the Visual Studio 10 compiler, which generated a bunch of Visual Studio projects. I compiled those projects into 2 libraries, and included the library directories in the project's properties. I also put all of PolyVox's header files in directories Visual Studio is aware of. When attempting to compile my project I get linker errors such as:

```
1>Gamestate.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall PolyVox::Region::Region(class PolyVox::Vector<3,int> const &,class PolyVox::Vector<3,int> const &)" (??0Region@PolyVox@@QAE@ABV?$Vector@$02H@1@0@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Gamestate::Gamestate(void)" (??0Gamestate@@QAE@XZ)
```

Could someone please explain to me how to properly include PolyVox into my code using Cmake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to add polyvox library in your game project. It's in the **Linker** menu and called "Additional dependencies", IIRC.

Comment: Bah, you are correct. Took me a whole day to fix such a stupid mistake. Thanks.